# Is cocos2d necessary for this?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

If I wanted to make an iPhone game like this one (ignoring the multiplayer functionality):

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/scramble-with-friends-free/id485084223?mt=8

Would it be wise to use cocos2d? Or would that be overkill? Or is another engine better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I think that Cocos2D would be a great choice, even if you don't need all of it now, you can build on top of it later. Cocos2D is just a wrapper for a 2D game and any board game is such. If you're dealing with a lot of animation it's probably a good choice, otherwise if it is mostly static and really simple UIKit and CoreGraphics may be a better bet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also interested in this type of game visual effects.  Scramble with friends seems to be mostly moving and rotation of the letter tiles (the collapsing effect at the beginning/end) and some funky fade in and transparency effects when touching the letters/using specials.
 
* Are those kind of effects easy with UIKit and CoreGraphics?
* Would using Cocos2D simplify the creation of these transparency effects/animations enough to justify the overhead?
 
(i realise this is a follow up question, but didnt know how else to revive this thread.)